# C# - Writing to a new word doc using data from database and downloading it at once

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create word documents where each document contains data pulled from an SQL database (each row populates one document). After this, there should be a button in the HTML which once clicked should download all these files in one go.

I've written the code (below) but only the first row of the database is being written to a file and downloaded. I'm not sure where the rest of the records are going or why they aren't being downloaded together with the first, even though it's in a loop.

This is the code:

```
...
OdbcDataReader dl = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (dl.Read())
{
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  string id = dl["application_id"].ToString();
  dt.Columns.Add("Id");
  dt.Columns.Add("Year");
  dt.Columns.Add("Season");
  dt.Columns.Add("Awarded Amount");
  dt.Rows.Add(id, GlobalMethods.proposalYear(), GlobalMethods.proposalSeason(),dl["awarded_amount"].ToString());

  dld(id, dt);
}
...

 protected void dld(string id, DataTable dt)
{
    //Create a dummy GridView
    GridView GridView1 = new GridView();
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    string fileName = "Proposal_" + id;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ".doc");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word ";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

I just started working with C# 3 days ago, so any help will be appreciated. Thank you!!!

Comment: You have not created a Word document. You've created an HTML file and then served it with Word file extension and MIME type. This is a bad idea. Not only do you have limited control over the presentation, but desktop Microsoft Word will complain about the file being corrupted, and many other Word clients will completely choke on the file. Don't be a [cargo cult programmer](https://exceptionnotfound.net/cargo-cult-programming-the-daily-software-anti-pattern/). Instead, use a library to generate a real Word document, such as [DocX](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX).

Comment: Hi, there's a little more to generating a word document than setting the content type and then uploading some grid data to it, but you've done well for 3 days in.  Most people tend to use some sort of reporting add-on to help output word or pdf documents, like SSRS (reporting services that comes with SQL Server).  You may want to consider outputting to a simple file format first, like a text file, before jumping to Word documents.

Comment: Thank you @mason, I'll look into the library! But just out of curiosity, do you know why the files aren't being downloaded one by one? I've been at this problem for a while so some clarity would help.

Comment: _"why the files aren't being downloaded one by one?"_ - you only get one response to a HTML request..

Comment: Thank you @stuartd

Comment: You should really split your problem. For example, you could place 3 premade word files into a folder on the server, then try to write the code that allows you to download them all when the user clicks some button. Then you will surely realize that the problem of downloading multiple documents is big enough for itself - without ever worrying about creating the documents from database.